# CollectionView is not refreshing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift5, uicollectionviewlayout

[image: tabs]

Here is my tags (tabs) and when I click to tag, collectionview is not refresh it. You can see on photo. How I can refresh - reload it. Also heightForItemAt method is not called 2nd time

[image]

[image]

Also when reload to collectionview , long scrollview and scroll indicator is on same position. I use custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout (PinterestLayout).

PinterestLayout code:

```
/**
* Copyright (c) 2019 Razeware LLC
*
*/

import UIKit


protocol PinterestLayoutDelegate: AnyObject {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, with width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
}

class PinterestLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
  // 1
  weak var delegate: PinterestLayoutDelegate?

  // 2
  private let numberOfColumns = 2
  private let cellPadding: CGFloat = 6

  // 3
  public var cache: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

  // 4
  private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

  private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
      return 0
    }
    let insets = collectionView.contentInset
    return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
  }

  // 5
  override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
  }
  
  override func prepare() {
    // 1
    /*guard
      cache.isEmpty == true,
      let collectionView = collectionView
      else {
        return
    }*/
     // cache.removeAll()
      
      guard let collectionView = collectionView else {return} // NEW BIT

    // 2
    let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
    var xOffset: [CGFloat] = []
    for column in 0..<numberOfColumns {
      xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
    }
    var column = 0
    var yOffset: [CGFloat] = .init(repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)
      
    // 3
    for item in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
      let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
        
      // 4

        let width = columnWidth - cellPadding * 2
        let photoHeight = delegate?.collectionView(collectionView, heightForItemAt: indexPath, with: width) ?? 0
        let height = cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
      let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column],
                         y: yOffset[column],
                         width: columnWidth,
                         height: height)
      let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)
        
      // 5
      let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
      attributes.frame = insetFrame
      cache.append(attributes)
        
      // 6
      contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
      yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height
        
      column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
    }
  }
  
  override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var visibleLayoutAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
    
    // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
    for attributes in cache {
      if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
        visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
      }
    }
    return visibleLayoutAttributes
  }
  
  override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cache[indexPath.item]
  }
}
```

taps click code:

```
       func tagsCollectionView(_ tagsCollectionView: TagsCollectionView, didSelect model: TagModel) {
            guard let selectedCat = tagsView.selectedTag?.name else { return }
            guard let selectedSubCat = subtagsView.selectedTag?.name else { return }
            self.selectedCategory = selectedCat
            self.selectedSubcategory = selectedSubCat
           if selectedCategory == TagTypes.CLASSICS.stringValue() && selectedSubcategory == TagTypes.IMAGES.stringValue() {
    
              self.collectionViewArray = self.classicImageArray
    
           }else if selectedCategory == TagTypes.CLASSICS.stringValue() && selectedSubcategory == TagTypes.VIDEOS.stringValue() {
    
              self.collectionViewArray = self.classicVideoArray
    
           }else if selectedCategory == TagTypes.AESTHETICS.stringValue() {
    
              self.collectionViewArray = self.aestheticArray
    
           }
    
          collectionView.reloadData() 
    }
}
```

viewcontroller and viewdidload code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, PinterestLayoutDelegate {
    
    var customLayout: PinterestLayout? {
           let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? PinterestLayout
           layout?.delegate = self
           return layout
    }
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            collectionView!.isPrefetchingEnabled = false
        }
        
        
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = customLayout!
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftRightMargin, bottom: 0, right: leftRightMargin)
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, with width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        
        
        
        if selectedCategory == TagTypes.CLASSICS.stringValue()
        {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TemplateCell", for: indexPath)
             guard let cell2 = cell as? TemplateCell else {
                
                return CGFloat()
                
            }
            let myImageView = MemesManager.shared.imageArray[indexPath.row]
            let imageHeight:CGFloat = resizeImageHeightForCollectionViewWidth(collectionView: collectionView, imageView: myImageView)
            return imageHeight
        }
        return 190;

    }
    func resizeImageHeightForCollectionViewWidth(collectionView:UICollectionView ,imageView:UIImageView? ) -> CGFloat {
        
      let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width
      let spacingBetweenCells: CGFloat = 0
      let totalSpacing = spacingBetweenCells * 2 // Hücreler arasındaki toplam boşluk
      let cellWidth = (collectionViewWidth - totalSpacing) / 2 // 3 sütun olduğu için genişliği üçe bölelim
        
        
        guard let myImage = imageView!.image else {
            
            return CGFloat(0)
        }

      // calculate image height for collectionview
        let imageWidth = imageView!.image!.size.width
        let imageHeight = imageView!.image!.size.height
      let aspectRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight
      let cellHeight = cellWidth / aspectRatio
      return cellHeight
 
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //filteredPresets.count + 1
        //return MemesManager.shared.imageMemeArray.count
        return self.collectionViewArray.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        
        if (selectedCategory ==  TagTypes.CLASSICS.stringValue() && selectedSubcategory == TagTypes.VIDEOS.stringValue()){
            if let videoCell = cell as? TemplateCell {
                    // Call a method on the cell to load the video data
                    videoCell.loadVideo()
                }
        }

        
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      
    
        if (selectedCategory ==  TagTypes.CLASSICS.stringValue() && selectedSubcategory == TagTypes.VIDEOS.stringValue()){
            if let videoCell = cell as? TemplateCell {
                    // Call a method on the cell to load the video data
                videoCell.unloadVideo()
                }
        }
       
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TemplateCell", for: indexPath)
        
        if let cell = cell as? TemplateCell
        {
            
                     cell.imageView? = self.collectionViewArray[indexPath.row]

                
        }

        return cell
    }
   

}
```

[image]
[image]